# Doesn't umask apply to files?

Tags: permissions, files, umask

I have set the `umask` to `0`.
So:

```
$umask   
0000
```

I do
`echo 'test' > test.txt`
And `test.txt` is created. If I do: `ls -l test.txt` I see:
$ls -l test.txt
`-rw-rw-rw- 1 jim None 5 Jun 30 22:50 test.txt`
Why aren't the rights `rwxrwxrwx`?

Comment: The shell doesn't set the `x` bit for newly created files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell uses 0666 for the default permissions when creating a new file. As umask only removes permissions, never adds them, that is what the resultant file will have.